# XsdDataContractExporter will not compile an Xsd schema with an <xs:attribute /> element

Tags: c#, wcf, xsd, wsdl

I have a WCF service with a basicHttpBinding endpoint. One of the types included in one of the data contracts implements IXmlSerializable and includes an XmlSchemaProvider that returns the contents of an Xsd file embedded in the assembly. When I hit the endpoint in the browser, the Wsdl generation fails, "XmlSchemaException: The 'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace:lang' attribute is not declared." There is an issue compiling the embedded Xsd file.

I did some research and discovered that the DataContractSerializer (and XsdDataContractExporter) do not support all serializable types (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923(v=vs.110).aspx). I suspect this behavior is at work here because the embedded Xsd includes a required attribute.

I also dotPeeked the XsdDataContractExporter code and found that get_Schemas compiles the imported schema set before returning and this is what is failing.

As a workaround, I modified the WCF service to use XmlSerializer instead of DataContractSerializer and the Wsdl generates OK. Has anyone experienced this behavior before? Thoughts?

Here is a console application and sample Xsd that will reproduce the error.

```
using System;
using System.Resources;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace SchemaCompiler
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var exporter = new XsdDataContractExporter();

            if (!exporter.CanExport(typeof(Foo)))
                return;

            exporter.Export(typeof(Foo));

            // The following line will throw XmlSchemaException: The 'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace:lang' attribute is not declared.
            var schemaSet = exporter.Schemas;   

            Console.WriteLine(schemaSet.IsCompiled);
        }

        [Serializable]
        [XmlSchemaProvider("GetSchema")]
        public class Foo : IXmlSerializable
        {
            private static XmlSchema _xmlSchema;

            public String Bar { get; set; }
            public String Language { get; set; }

            public static XmlQualifiedName GetSchema(XmlSchemaSet schemaSet)
            {
                var type = typeof(Foo);

                var xsdFileStream = type.Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(type, "Foo.xsd");
                if (xsdFileStream == null) throw new MissingManifestResourceException(
                        "The embedded resource Foo.xsd was not found. For more information, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292");

                _xmlSchema = XmlSchema.Read(xsdFileStream, null);
                schemaSet.Add(_xmlSchema);

                return new XmlQualifiedName(type.Name, "http://tempuri.org/Foo.xsd");
            }

            #region IXmlSerializable Members

            public XmlSchema GetSchema()
            {
                return _xmlSchema;
            }

            public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            #endregion
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the sample Xsd file that you will need to embed in the assembly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="Foo" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Foo.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" />
  <xs:complexType name="Foo" mixed="false">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Value">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
              <xs:attribute ref="xml:lang" use="required" />
            </xs:extension>
          </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your analysis may be correct.  But the error message complains about an undeclared attribute, not about an unsupported construct, so I wonder if there is another explanation.

Your schema document should be fine if the software that uses it knows where to find a schema document for the namespace `http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace`.  But most XSD software I am familiar with doesn't have built-in knowledge of that namespace.  I wonder if your initial setup would work better if you changed the import to read something like this:

```
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" 
           schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2009/01/xml.xsd"/>
```

N.B. [W3C serves schemas and DTDs very very slowly](http://www.w3.org/Help/Webmaster.html#slowdtd) (it's a long story), so you may prefer (even just for testing, and certainly for serious work) to make a local copy of the schema document for the XML namespace (the URI is given in the example) and point to your local copy instead.